# Fetch all data from RESTApi from multiple arrays

Tags: php, api

i'm built my own rest api it works fine when i request to link i can add,delete or edit data but i can't fetch data to my web application. I used json_decode function to convert JSON to array and when i checked it, my api stores every single row in one array so i have multiple arrays in my api. Here is my var_dump() output:

```
array(5) {
  [0] => array(3) {
    ["id"] => string(1)
    "1" ["title"] => string(88)
    "Twitter, Yanıt İstemleri Özelliğini Twitter’ı Türkçe Kullanan Herkese Getiriyor" ["details"] => string(1443)
    "Twitter, Türkçe Yanıt İstemleri özelliğinin başarılı geçen deneme sürecinden sonra, bu özelliğin 2 Ağustos’tan itibaren iOS, Android ve Web için globalde Twitter’ı Türkçe dilinde kullanan kullanıcıların tümüne sunacağını açıkladı. Twitter, bu özelliği 2022’nin başından bu yana, dünyanın çeşitli bölgelerinde test ediyordu. Reply Prompts yani Yanıt İstemleri özelliği, bir Tweet’e yanıt olarak zararlı olabilecek bir dil (hakaret, kaba dil veya nefret dolu sözler) algıladığımızda görünür. Bu özellik, insanlara yazdıklarını yeniden düşünme ve potansiyel olarak yanıtı silme veya değiştirme şansı veriyor. Twitter’dan yapılan açıklamada, şu ifadelere yer verildi: “Geçen yıl, konuşmaları daha medeni hale getirmenin ve Twitter’daki genel konuşmanın sağlığını iyileştirmenin bir yolu olarak ABD ve Brezilya’daki insanlara yönelik yanıt istemleri özelliğini başlattık. Bu test, ABD’deki kişilerin %30’unun ve Brezilya’daki kişilerin %47’sinin, sorulduktan sonra yanıtlarını değiştirmesi veya silmesiyle sonuçlandı. Bu özelliği Türkçe olarak test ettikten sonra, tüm dünyada Türkçe dil ayarlarına sahip olan herkese sunmaya hazırız. Bu başarıyı dünyanın her yerindeki insanların Twitter’daki deneyimlerine yansıtmak amacıyla bu özelliği farklı pazarlarda ve dillerde de test etmeye devam edeceğiz.”"
  } [1] => array(3) {
    ["id"] => string(1)
    "2" ["title"] => string(55)
    "Ericsson, Qualcomm ve Thales, 5G’yi Uzaya Taşıyacak" ["details"] => string(5112)
    "Ericsson, Fransız havacılık ve uzay şirketi Thales ve kablosuz teknoloji geliştiricisi Qualcomm Technologies ile birlikte 5G’yi dünyanın sınırlarının dışına çıkarıp, yörüngedeki uydulardan meydana gelen bir ağ oluşturmayı planlıyor. Projeyle birlikte geleceğin 5G akıllı telefonlarının kullanım alanı genişleyecek. Bu sayede yalnızca veri bağlantısı sunan geleneksel uydu telefonları yoluyla iletişim kurulabilen bölgelerle sınırlı kalınmayıp, dünyanın her yerinde 5G bağlantıdan ve geniş bant veri hizmetlerinden yararlanabilme potansiyeline erişilecek. Alçak Dünya Yörüngesinde (ADY) bulunan uydular yoluyla sağlanan 5G bağlantının en zorlu coğrafyaları; denizleri, okyanusları ve karasal bağlantı imkanının bulunmadığı diğer ücra bölgeleri kapsama alanına dahil etmesi bekleniyor. Bu ölçüde yaygın bir kapsama alanının, hem 5G akıllı telefon abonelerine sunulan dolaşım hizmetlerini iyileştirmesi, hem de taşımacılık, enerji ve sağlık sektörlerinin 5G kullanım senaryolarından yararlanması amaçlanıyor. Uzay tabanlı ağlar aynı zamanda karasal ağların beklenmedik kesintiler veya doğal afetler sebebiyle kullanılamadığı durumlarda yedek iletişim ağı olarak görev yapabilecek. Ericsson Kıdemli Başkan Yardımcısı ve CTO’su Erik Ekudden konuyla ilgili şunları kaydetti: “Ericsson, Thales ve Qualcomm Technologies’in bu teknolojiyi test etmek ve doğrulamak için kurduğu iş birliği, iletişim tarihinde önemli bir kilometre taşı olma niteliği taşıyor. Nihayetinde bu teknoloji, birlikte çalışan 5G uydular ve karasal bağlantılar yoluyla gerek okyanusun ortasında gerek ücra bir bölgedeki ormanın içinde olsun, dünyanın her noktasındaki kullanıcılara gelişmiş, güvenli ve ulaşılabilir iletişim imkanı sunacak. Ericsson Türkiye Genel Müdürü Işıl Yalçın, “Ericsson’un sınırsız olasılıklar sunan sınırsız bağlantılar vizyonu, yavaş yavaş gerçeğe dönüşüyor. Ericsson, Thales ve Qualcomm Technologies arasındaki test ve validasyon işbirliği, okyanuslar ve ormanlar gibi dünyanın en ücra ve zorlu bölgelerinde bağlantı imkanı sağlayacak. Bu da herkesin ve her şeyin, her yerden güvenli ve uygun maliyetli bir şekilde birbirine bağlanabileceği bir dünyanın kapısını aralıyor. Aynı zamanda mevcut karasal ağların doğal afetler sebebiyle hizmet vermediği durumlarda yedek iletişim ağı olarak görev yapabilecek olması da önemli bir değer yaratıyor” açıklamasını yaptı. Qualcomm Technologies Mühendislikten Sorumlu Kıdemli Başkan Yardımcısı John Smee, şu açıklamayı yaptı: “5G’nin her yerde her zaman bağlantı sağlama taahhüdünün yerine getirilebilmesi için, bu ağın kapsama alanının okyanuslar ve ücra bölgeler gibi karasal hücresel ağların ulaşamadığı noktalara da genişletilmesi şart. Ericsson ve Thales ile birlikte planladığımız bu araştırma sayesinde, hayati bir öneme sahip bu teknolojiyi gerçeğe dönüştürmek yolunda önemli bir adım atmış olacağız. Bu iş birliğinin neler başarabileceğini görmek için sabırsızlanıyoruz.” Thales Strateji, Araştırma ve Teknolojiden Sorumlu Kıdemli Başkan Yardımcısı Philippe Keryer, şu değerlendirmede bulundu: “5G ağlarının hizmete alınması, telekomünikasyon endüstrisi için büyük bir değişime işaret ediyor. Bu, yalnızca sunduğu iş fırsatları açısından değil, aynı zamanda milyarlarca insanı ve nesneyi birbirine bağlamak ve güvenliklerini sağlamak için sunduğu özellikler yönünden de oyunun kurallarını değiştiren bir gelişme. Thales, bu ortak araştırma grubunun birçok çalışmasıyla yakından ilgileniyor. Ericsson ve Qualcomm Technologies ile kurduğumuz bu iş birliği, 5G karasal olmayan ağların devrimsel özelliğine ve ağ dayanıklılığı ile güvenliğini sonraki seviyeye taşıma potansiyeline olan inancımızın bir göstergesi niteliğinde.” Küresel telekomünikasyon standartları kurumu 3GPP’nin Mart 2022’de verdiği onayın ardından, Ericsson, Thales ve Qualcomm Technologies’in başlattığı bu ilk test ve validasyon çalışmasında karasal olmayan ağların desteklenmesi amaçlanıyor. Test kapsamında, 5G karasal olmayan ağları oluşturacak 5G akıllı telefonlar, uydular ve karadaki 5G ağ bileşenleri gibi çeşitli teknoloji unsurlarının validasyonu gerçekleştirilecek. Ericsson, hızla hareket eden ADY uydular aracılığıyla yayılan radyo sinyallerini yakalamak üzere modifiye edilen bir 5G sanal RAN (vRAN) kümesini test ederek, uzay boşluğu ile Dünya’nın atmosferi arasında geçiş yapan 5G radyo dalgalarında ne gibi değişimler olduğu sorusuna yanıt arayacak. Thales ADY uydularda kullanıma uygun bir 5G radyo uydu sistemini test etmeyi planlarken, Qualcomm Technologies ise 5G NTN’lerin geleceğin 5G akıllı telefonlarında kullanılabileceğini kanıtlamak amacıyla geliştirilmiş test telefonlarından yararlanacak."
  }
```

So i use

```
 $result = $data[0];
 echo '<a href="newsDetails.php"><h3>'.$result['title'].'</h3></a>';
```

codes after i convert json data to array but as you can see, i can only fetch one data in array(0). So how can i print several datas using foreach method. How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop through all of them and print the title of each can be done in this way with a foreach loop:

```
foreach($result as $row){
    echo '<a href="newsDetails.php"><h3>'.$row['title'].'</h3></a>';
}
```